# How to update the dropdown options in ttk.OptionsMenu (python, tkinter, ttk)

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, addition, ttk

I have found plenty of documentation on how to update a OptionsMenu object using tkinter but due to various issues revolving around my version of mac OS, I have been using ttk to build my project and I've found myself stumped when it comes to updating the options menu.

My options are coming from a list which is added using the following code:

```
dropdown_menu = ttk.OptionMenu(root, dropdown_menu_text, dropdown_options[0], *dropdown_options)
```

and I am using a separate method to update the contents of the `dropdown_options` variable. According to the information I found, updating the optionsmenu using standard tk involves essentially clearing the options, then looping through my updated list and adding each option back again.

Is it a similar kind of logic with ttk?

Comment: Why don't you use `ttk.Combobox`

Comment: Have you tried using the logic that works with the standard `tkinter`? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that I completely misread your question so I deleted my old answer. Yes, I tried the logic, but it seems to hinge on the OptionsMenu having a ['menu'] attribute, so the associated properties could be cleared and replaced with the new menu items. Unfortunately the ttk OptionsMenu does not have such a property so I was unable to follow the logic. That said, I was able to find a solution included in my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out after some more digging around I was able to find the solution myself and it was far simpler than I anticipated. Turns out the answer is simply to add the line

```
dropdown_menu.set_menu(dropdown_options[0], * dropdown_options)
```

Assuming that dropdown_options is your updated list!